# Doxygen not recognizing documented functions et al

Tags: c, doxygen

I'm just getting started with doxygen (1.9.0).  I've added what I believe are correct comment blocks to several functions as well as a `typedef` and an `enum` in my C project.  However, when I run `doxygen dconfig`, the resultant HTML only contains my source code and none of the documentation.

Here's an example of my documentation.

```
/**
*   \enum grrRetValue
*   \brief Function return values.
*
*   Any function in the Grr API which returns an int returns one of these
*   values.
*/
enum grrRetValue {
    GRR_RET_OK = 0, //!< The function succeeded.
    GRR_RET_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, //!< The requested functionality has not yet been implemented.
    GRR_RET_DONE, //!< A recursive task has finished.
    GRR_RET_NOT_FOUND, //!< The requested item was not found.
    GRR_RET_OUT_OF_MEMORY, //!< Memory allocation failure.
    GRR_RET_BAD_DATA, //!< Invalid data was passed to the function.
    GRR_RET_FILE_ACCESS, //!< A file read/write failed.
    GRR_RET_OVERFLOW, //!< A buffer overflow occurred.
    GRR_RET_EXEC, //!< A call to exec failed.
    GRR_RET_OTHER, //!< A generic error occurred which is not covered by the above options.
};

/**
*   \typedef grrNfa
*   \brief An opaque reference to Grr's regex object.
*/
typedef struct grrNfaStruct *grrNfa;
```

And

```
/**
*   \fn grrCompile
*   \brief Compiles a string into a regex object.
*   \param string The string to be compiled (does not have to be zero-terminated).
*   \param len The length of the string.
*   \param nfa A pointer to the Grr regex object to be populated.
*   \return GRR_RET_OK if successful and an error code otherwise.
*
*   Possible error codes:
*       - GRR_RET_OUT_OF_MEMORY
*       - GRR_RET_BAD_DATA (the string contained non-printable characters)
*/
int grrCompile(const char *string, size_t len, grrNfa *nfa);
```

Let me know if you need to see any of the options from `dconfig`.

Comment: Have you followed a HelloWorld-based tutorial for doxygen? By which I mean have you reproduced a known good simple example?

Comment: I have not.  I'd be grateful if you could point me to one to try.

Comment: I've been trying to follow the documentation at [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html).

Comment: Actaully the first thing I did was not a Tutorial. I used the DoxyGen support in my favorite free programming IDE. It has a plugin which did not led my down.

Comment: And I have to admit that there is no obviously most inviting tutorial when searching for it. But there are some to choose from. Let me note that the resoruce which are on ".nl" sites are in English (not dutch). Most talk first about how to instrument your code (which you seem to have already done, and done plausibly), so you have to skip a few pages and look for anything about how to set up and run.

Comment: This is the "is it plugged in?" question: Do you have `\file` in a doxygen comment at the start of your file?

Comment: It would definitely be useful to see you settings. For the 1.9.0 version (you apparently compiled yourself from master, what is the full identification `doxygen -v`?) use `doxygen -x dconfig` which shows the differences with the default doxygen settings and is sufficient.

Comment: @DavidHoadley, sigh.  That was it.  Want to post that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These symptoms look very much like a missing `\file` command. Place a doxygen comment at the start of your file like `/** \file */` and try again.